# Excel Formula Help: Within 1 week, but no more than one week

Tags: excel, formula

I am looking to create a formula in which

1. if the date is passed today it will display "OVERDUE",
2. if the date is within 7 days from today/a week from today then it would display "1 week left",
3. but if the date is more than a week away then the cell will remain blank.

The Overdue and 1 week left command are working, but not the third. I don't know how to contain the 1 week formula to just within 1 week so that it doesn't overlap with the third.

e28 and down is my date assigned column
g28 and down is my reminder/status column

> =IF(ISBLANK(E28),"", IF(E28TODAY()-7,"1 WEEK LEFT!", IF(E28>TODAY()-8,""))))

*sorry I'm new. This post is erasing my less than and greater than signs.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
=IF(E28-TODAY()>0,"Overdue",IF(TODAY()-E28<=7,"1 WEEK LEFT",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E28),"",IF(E28<TODAY(),"OVERDUE",IF(E28-TODAY()<=7,"1 WEEK LEFT!",IF(E28-TODAY()>7,""))))
```